# How to fix Failed to update the following work item:ID xxxx. Reason: TF401319: Rule evaluation failed for field Resolved By

Tags: azure-devops, settings, rules

When I checked-in a code change,I associated a work item.I got the following error message: 
"
Failed to update the following work item:ID xxxx. Reason: TF401319: Rule evaluation failed for field Resolved By."
I understand that this is failing because of a rule set related to field Resolved by...
Where can I find these rules that are set ,in Visual studio or Azure Dev ops?

I tried to find the rules in visual studio but couldn't find source control settings in Visual studio -> Team Explorer -> Project Settings

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I find these rules that are set ,in Visual studio or Azure
>   Dev ops?

Go Organization setting-> process-> open the process(your project are using).

[image]

And then, open the relevant work item type which you are trying to associate but failed with error. For example, user story.

And change to the **Rule** tab, then need check the relevant rule configuration which configured with Resolved By and let you meet the error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but there are no custom rules for the work item type that I tried to associate. IS it something to do with the Visual studio settings?

Comment: @likhitayadama Can you share more details about your operations? Did you associated the work item while you check in code in Visual Studio?